# Trouble while setup Flutter with Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

So I tried to setup my Flutter app with Firebase. I follow the documentation already. But, when i run the app it return error

```
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
      > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 45s
```

I guess it's related with my `build.gradle` So here is mine.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

I already tried

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

but nothing work.I'm new to Flutter and this is my first project using Firebase. I'm not sure how to solve this error.

Comment: Could you please provide the version of Flutter and Firebase you are using? Also, could you share the content of your app-level build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your google-services version:

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10
```

to

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14
```